# Run a development environment VM on SSD or on second drive

Tags: windows-7, ssd, vmware-player

I have a new machine with an SSD as the primary drive, running 64-bit Windows 7, and a 7200 RPM 500GB drive as the secondary drive.

I have a VM set up under VMWare that has a development environment within it (Windows XP with VS2010 and MySQL).

Would it be better for the performance within the VM to run this VM on the SSD or the second hard drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would get better performance running from the SSD than the mechanical drive, as long as the SSD is big enough for your needs.

Comment: +1. I keep my most frequently accessed VMs on my SSD primary drive, and then my less frequent VMs on my secondary mechanical. Or I'll swap VMs around if I'm going to be using one frequently for a while.